# Constructing maps between retracts from maps between the large objects B?

Tags: category-theory

In Lawvere and Schanuel's book (Conceptual Mathematics), after exercise which attempts to show that there is essentially one split for a given idempotent (Page number 102) Following is said about further study: "**One can even study how to reconstruct maps between retracts from maps between the large objects** $B$."

Doubts are described below:

I have no clue as to **what maps between large objects B are**. Why did he just **use $B$ to identify large objects**, is $B$ a collection of large objects? Are **retracts between objects $B$ or some other objects**?

[image: A snapshot of concerned section of book]

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more details for those of us who do not have this book.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, thanks for letting me know, I have now added a screenshot of that section of book.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a typo: it should be "*on* the large object $B$".

The notation of Exercise 3 is used here, $B$ can be thought as a fixed object, and the maps $s,s'$ are monomorphisms from $A$, resp. $A'$, i.e. these are *subobjects* of $B$, and this is the meaning of 'large' here.

We can define the category of retracts of $B$ with morphisms $(A,r,s) \to (A',r',s')$ those $f:A\to A'$ that make both arising triangles commutative.

Now, if $(A,r,s)$ is split by idempotent $e:B\to B\ $ [i.e., $e=s\circ r$], and $(A',r',s')$ by $e'$, consider all the maps $\bar f:B\to B$ that satisfy $e'\circ \bar f\circ e=\bar f$.

Finally, show that there's a natural bijective correspondence between the $f$'s and $\bar f$'s above.

Comment: @ Berci I understood subobjects as equivalence classes of monomorphisms under the relation that a monomorphism $f: A \rightarrow B$ is equivalent to monomorphism $g: A' \rightarrow B$ iff $f$ can be factored through $g$ and vice versa. Right? Also,I do not understand, what triangles are arising in this, could you draw a object and arrow diagram for one such triangle that is commutative? I wonder what do you mean by natural bijection, I found many definitions relying on concept of natural transformation and functor (Not understood that yet). I think I will learn those later on in the same book.